# Symfony sfMail not delivering emails

Tags: email, symfony1

somehow sfMail doesn't want to send emails and I can't find the reason why. `send()` simply returns 0, here is my code:

```
$message = $this->getMailer()->compose("my@email.com", "some@one.com", "test", "testing");
echo $this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

factories.yml:

```
all:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
    logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
    charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
    delivery_strategy: realtime
    transport:
      class: Swift_SmtpTransport
      param:
        host:       smtp.email.com
        port:       25
        encryption: ~
        username:   my@email.com
        password:   mytestpass
```

and I simply get "0" as result. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: in my Apache log I found this: "sendmail: Cannot open mail:25", I'm 100% sure that my smtp server is working just fine...

Comment: Is there anything related in symfony's logs ? or information through sfMail's getLogger  method ?

Comment: there is nothing in symfony logs but in apache logs i got: "sendmail: Cannot open mail:25". is he trying to use my local mail server? I set in factories class: Swift_SmtpTransport...

Comment: Are outgoing connections to port 25 blocked by your work/ISP connection at all?

Comment: no, it's my home pc, I can check emails from this account with my email client without any problems

Answer (score -2):

First of all in your params you have a host named smtp.email.com .. I don't think that is a legit host of yours. What Swift_SmtpTransport does is connects with the host and tries to send an e-mail with it's help via smtp. So be sure to get a proper SMTP configuration params from you server. The host and the port are important

Comment: These are probably just example data for the purposes of posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: could be, but that could also be the problem if copying from example

Comment: it's just an example, I also don't have my@email.com as my email address... ;)